# Insert tabs with .join in python

Tags: python

This is probably basic, but I can't find a solution.  I have a string, e.g.,

```
s = 'a,b,c,d'
```

I'd like to convert the commas to tabs.  But using .replace, e.g.,

```
s.replace(',', '\t')
```

gives me

```
>>> s.replace(',', '\t')
'a\tb\tc\td'
```

I also tried converting to a list and then adding the tabs with a .join, e.g.,

```
'\t'.join(s.split(','))
```

but that gives the same result.  How can I have the tabs actually inserted as tabs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> print s.replace(',', '\t')
a    b    c    d
```

Right now you are see'ing `repr(s.replace(',', '\t'))` in the interpreter without the print statement.  `repr()` will show each actual character in a string and the interpreter uses that as the default method to print out the result of operations.

Unless you wanted 4 spaces instead; which would just be:

```
>>> print s.replace(',', (' '*4))
a    b    c    d
```